# Error: Unable to open include file: 'unicode / ucsdet.h': No such file or directory

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

I'm trying to install `linguist` using PyCharm but i receive this error

```
fatal error C1083: Unable to open include file: 'unicode/ucsdet.h': No such file or directory
```

The error appears when installing `charlockholmes`

I also installed `Microsoft C++ build tools` as required during the first time installation.

```
Python version 3.9.6
Pip version 21.1.3
```

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 10 (21H1) Build: 19043.1110

Comment: https://github.com/douban/PyCharlockHolmes#dependency: [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/download); [libmagic](https://github.com/nscaife/file-windows).

Comment: I have already installed PyICU and libmagic but charlockholmes does not install